# Computing the measure of a set difference

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Say that $E$ is of finite measure and we have closed subsets $B_1, B_2$ such that $|E - B_1| < \epsilon_1$, $|E - B_2| < \epsilon_2.$ How can I write $|E - B_1 \cup B_2|$ in relation to $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $E - B_1 \cup B_2 \subset E - B_1$ and $E - B_1 \cup B_2 \subset E - B_2$, so by monotonicity,
$$
|E-B_1 \cup B_2| \le |E - B_1| \\
|E-B_2 \cup B_2| \le |E-B_2|
$$

Comment: Wow I brain farted so hard. Thank you.